# Mouseover image pulls other images down

Tags: html, image, mouseover

I'm having this problem with the images of the website I'm making. I've been trying different ways to solve it and this was the best I found so far. Still, it's not what I need. I have 8 buttons and I need the second one to be replaced by a bigger image. The thing is, it pulls the others down, and I wanted it to be over them. Is there a way to do it? This is what I did in the coding:

```
<a href="index.html">
<input type="image" src="hp-homebutton.png" alt="submit" style="position: relative;" value="Home Button"/> </a> <p>
<img src="hp-monthsbutton.png" onmouseover="this.src='hp-months.png'" onmouseout="this.src='hp-monthsbutton.png'" style="position: relative;"/> <p>
<img src="hp-forumbutton.png" style="position: relative;"/> <p>
<img src="hp-newsbutton.png" style="position: relative;"/> <p>
<img src="hp-contactbutton.png" style="position: relative;"/> <p>
<input type="image" src="hp-eventsbutton.png" alt="submit" style="position: relative;" value="Events Button" onclick="showImage();"/> <p>
<img src="hp-gallerybutton.png" style="position: relative;"/> <p>
<img src="hp-extrasbutton.png" style="position: relative;"/> <p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I correctly understand what you want to achieve, you need to wrap your images inside elements, and give that parent a fixed height. Then you can add `z-index` to your images to ensure the correct image appears ontop. Check the demo below, I have changed your HTML slightly to demonstrate the principle.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cu54n/3/)**

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html"><img src="http://s21.postimg.org/hzb9gge93/hp_homebutton.png" alt="Home" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s21.postimg.org/bbentuuqv/hp_monthsbutton.png" alt="Months" onmouseover="this.src='http://s21.postimg.org/8ssyt690n/hp_months.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://s21.postimg.org/bbentuuqv/hp_monthsbutton.png'" class="months" /></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s21.postimg.org/rer4tnw9z/hp_forumbutton.png" alt="Forum" /></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s21.postimg.org/ig12gmrdz/hp_newsbutton.png" alt="News" /></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li {
    clear: both;
    height: 54px;
}

ul li img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

ul li .months {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: I tried to do like you suggested, but I'm still finding some issues with the coding. Thing is, if I change the image position to absolute, but that only made the others cover it.
`<div style="position: relative;">
       <img src="hp-monthsbutton.png" onmouseover="this.src='hp-months.png'" onmouseout="this.src='hp-monthsbutton.png'" style="position: absolute;"/> <p>
</div>`

Comment: @Caracks Can you please create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating the problem? Then I will be able to assist you further.

Comment: Alright, I created a JSFiddle showing the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/LB24X/

As you can see, the second image, for being a `position: absolute`, makes the others cover it. You can still make the mouseover image appear and see it under the others though.

Comment: @Caracks Ok, I understand what it is you want to do now. I have edited my answer to show you the best way to do this.